# JS something weird with multiplication and parseFloat()

Tags: javascript, math

Ok so, this is what I have

```
amount = parseFloat("0.07") * 100;
```

and this is what I get in return

```
7.000000000000001
```

Could anyone tell me why? It only happens with 0.07... Other numbers convert correctly, 0.01 or 0.06 for instance.

Comment: Please read http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic"